# this go-round -- what does that mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Source: [CompTIA Network+ Certification All-in-One Exam Guide, 6th Edition (Exam N10-006) by Mike Meyers (2015)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071848223)

Example:

> To Travis Everett, Internet guru and writer: Such a wonderful addition to the team **this go-round**, not just as a top-notch editor, but as a contributor as well. Your understanding of the Internet and the Cloud added excellent additions to the book. Looking forward to the next one to see what other talents you bring to the table!

What exactly does that mean?

Comment: This is pretty common. Have you done any research? Consider that "round" may be alternated with "around".

Comment: No idea. It doesn't make any sense to me. (Native BrE speaker)

Comment: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/go-round

Comment: @NathanTuggy My virus detector (Avast) gave me a warning concerning that link.  I just visited again (dictionary.com is a reputable site), and there was no complaint. Unsure what that signifies, but it seemed like I should say something.

Comment: this go round =  this iteration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *go* round

does not mean "look around" or "going around" to different places, it means

> this time around

I have more often encountered this saying in BrE where the expression

> have a *go*

means to try to do *something*.

The book you reference is in its 6th edition, meaning it has been editted and reedited 6 times, it has had 6 "rounds" of releases, this latest "round" (this *go round*) includes Travis Everett.

A hint as to what it means s in the last sentence if the passage you have quoted "Looking forward to the next one to see what other talents you bring to the table!",  for the next *go round*.